# Unable to enable disabled input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Input elements can be easily disabled but what way is there to enable them?

The below code can disable but not enable the input element.

```js
$('#dis').click(function() {
  $('#inp').attr('disabled', 'true');
});

$('#enb').click(function() {
  $('#inp').attr('disabled', 'false');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='inp' type='text'>
<button id='enb'>Enable</button>
<button id='dis'>Disable</button>
```

Comment: Do not user $().attr() user $().prop() instead. See http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just to expand on the answer...

The real problem is that you are trying to set disabled to false via `setAttribute()` which doesn't behave as you are expecting. An element is disabled if the disabled-attribute is set, regardless of value
so, `disabled="true"`, `disabled="disabled"` and `disabled="false"` are all equivalent: the element gets disabled).

You should instead remove the complete attribute

```
$('#enb').click(function() {
   $('#inp').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

Answer (score 6):

The issue was with your code having `true` and `false` written in quotes, making them strings instead of booleans. Note that both `'true'` and `'false'` are truthy values, and thus your code set the enabled value to true in both cases.

I expect the following will work for you, check the snippet as well:

```js
$('#dis').click(function() {
    $("#inp").prop('disabled', true);
});

$('#enb').click(function() {
    $("#inp").prop('disabled', false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='inp' type='text'>
<button id='enb'>Enable</button>
<button id='dis'>Disable</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

Just remove the `disabled` attribute

```
$('#enb').click(function() {
   $('#inp').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

Comment: This is not a good practice. from the documentation: `Do not use this method to remove native properties such as checked, disabled, or selected.`

Comment: why not? any insights @NitaiJ.Perez?

Comment: @anurageldorado, the docs mention it may remove the prop/attr permanently, not allowing it to be re-set.

Comment: So it's not so harmful in all the cases right?

Comment: @anurageldorado, why take the risk? See my answer for a safe method.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`removeAttr()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/)

```js
$('#dis').click(function() {
  $('#inp').attr('disabled', 'true');
});

$('#enb').click(function() {
  $('#inp').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='inp' type='text'>
<button id='enb'>Enable</button>
<button id='dis'>Disable</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Hi Try the below code**

There is different between Boolean values and strings instead of ***'true'*** use ***true*** without **quotes**

```js
$('#dis').click(function() {
  $('#inp').attr('disabled', true);
});

$('#enb').click(function() {
  $('#inp').attr('disabled', false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='inp' type='text'>
<button id='enb'>Enable</button>
<button id='dis'>Disable</button>
```

Comment: Again, the attr() Method does not work with boolean values

Comment: @Lacrioque who is saying?

Comment: Jquey online documentation:  http://api.jquery.com/prop/ See Attributes versus Properties

Comment: Answer for what you said about using Boolean values..

Comment: Pre 1.6 Jquery used boolean values with attr() I give you that, but after the prop() Method got introduced, the documentation clearly states, that using boolean values with attr() will cause errors. If you have a working code great! But again boolean values should not be used with attr()

Answer (score 1):

```
<scriptsrc="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='inp' type='text'>
<button id='enb'>Enable</button>
<button id='dis'>Disable</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {

$( "#dis" ).click(function() {
  $('#inp').prop( "disabled", true );

});

$( "#enb" ).click(function() {
  $('#inp').prop( "disabled", false );
});

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('#dis').click(function() {
  $('#inp').attr('disabled', 'true');
});

$('#enb').click(function() {
  $('#inp').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

because `disable="disable"`  is equal to `disable` itself

Answer (score 0):

There is a way! You need to remove the disabled attribute like so :

```
$('#inp').removeAttr('disabled');
```